# Octave script through php windows

Tags: php, windows, octave

I am trying to run an octave script through PHP. I already googled and found some results but none of them are working for me. I tried with exec() and system(). I even created a batch file which calls 'octave myScript.m" and called this bat file using system() of PHP but it doesnt seem to work. In the browser page I am just seeing 'C:/FOLDER_PATH>octave myScript.m". The octave script simply creates a new file and writes some text to it. When i directly run the bat file (by double-clicking on it), the file is getting created properly. I also added folder path to octaverc file but it doesnt seem to work. I need to do some image processing in octave for which I already wrote the script. I need to invoke this script on a client request and send the result to back the client. I am checking the invocation process through a sample script which as I mentioned earlier creates a new file. What am I doing wrong?

My php code is this:

```
$cmd = "cmd /c C:\PATH_TO_BAT_FILE\myBat.bat";
exec($cmd,$output);
system($cmd);
echo implode ("\n",$output);
```

Note that my path contains double backslashes to avoid escape sequence characters

My bat file is this

```
octave temp.m
```

My octave code(temp.m) is this

```
fid = fopen("helloScript.txt",'w');
fprintf(fid,"Hello world!");
fclose(fid);
```

Ouput on the webpage is this:

```
C:\PATH_TO_BAT_FILE>octave temp.m C:\PATH_TO_BAT_FILE>octave temp.m
```

I can see in the task manager that a new process is getting created whenever I run the PHP script in browser (I am guessing that it is cmd).
Also, when i change my bat file to

```
echo hello
```

I am able to see the following in my browser page

```
 C:\PATH_TO_BAT_FILE>echo hello hello C:\PATH_TO_BAT_FILE>echo hello hello
```

So this could mean that the bat file is getting executed properly. But when I replace the bat file script with 'octave MY_FILE.m' I am not able to see the output. It may mean that my octave is not configured properly? or is there something I am missing?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: If you can see php sourcecode in the source then you dont have php enabled.

Comment: Could you please explain? I didnt understand

Comment: Its what I deduced from: In the browser page I am just seeing 'C:/FOLDER_PATH>octave myScript.m".

Comment: Actually can you show us what code you are trying.

Comment: edited the question to include my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is embarassing but I solved it by giving full path. In the bat file I specified the complete path of the octave.exe   (C:\Software\PATH_TO_OCTAVE.EXE) and the complete path of the '.m' file.
In my php, I just used exec()

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to run the batch file to create it in php then the php command should be like this.

```
exec('cmd.exe /c C:\path\to\test.bat');
```

Comment: I already tried that. It is not working. My php code is this:

Comment: Would it not be `cmd.exe /c C:\\path\\to\\test.bat`? else your get tabs for the \t

Comment: @LozCherone Yes I believe you are right, it shouldn't need to be escaped unless you use double quotes. Changed it.

Comment: edited the question. Hope it makes my question clearer